# Extension installed - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: extensions, shipping, sql

I have a rather odd problem I haven't encountered before.

I installed the Premium MatrixRate extension on Magento 1.9 according to their guide. When I go to Configuration > Shipping Methods (to try and configure it) I get the following error:

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydbname.shipping_premiumrate' doesn't exist

Trace:
#0 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(651): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#8 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getData()
#9 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(301): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Premiumrate/Model/Carrier/Premiumrate.php(312): Varien_Data_Collection->getItems()
#11 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Premiumrate/Model/Carrier/Premiumrate.php(271): Webshopapps_Premiumrate_Model_Carrier_Premiumrate->getSimpleAllowedMethods()
#12 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Premiumrate/Model/Carrier/Source/Freemethod.php(41): Webshopapps_Premiumrate_Model_Carrier_Premiumrate->getAllowedMethods()
#13 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(463): Webshopapps_Premiumrate_Model_Carrier_Source_Freemethod->toOptionArray(false)
#14 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#15 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#16 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#17 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#18 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#19 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#20 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/folder/public_html/mydomain.com/index.php(93): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Any idea will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the setup script of the module didn't run properly so you have to login to your admin panel and logout and back in again.

If this doesn't work and you have magerun available on your server then run the following commands:

if cache is this disabled:

```
magerun cache:enable
```

followed by:

```
magerun sys:setup:incremental
```

Now you will see if a new setup script has to run and you can manually run these by pressing the `enter` key.

Then flush the cache with the following command:

```
magerun cache:flush
```

Now the error should be solved.